# How to get the UISwitch thumb image / shadow that is used for default UISwitch on a given iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, shadow, uiswitch

How can I get the default UISwitch thumb image/shadow/etc for a given iOS?
I am building my own custom UISwitch and want the thumb imageview I created to look the same as the default UISwitch.

Comment: Can you share image of what you want OR describe in detail.

Comment: I am making my own UISwitch look a like object with so much unique functionality that I didn't want to subclass the default UISwitch. My goal is to somehow understand the radius and shadow properties of the default UISwitch on iOS 10, 9, and 8. I am unsure if these properties are static between these iOS version or not. Is there a way I can programmatically find these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called [iOS Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/ide/iOS-Artwork-Extractor/tree/3x) to help you extracting all images of simulator. Download the source code of this project, then run it on iPhone 7 simulator, search with keyword "switch", choose an image then press save button, it will be exported into your Desktop.